# How to deploy smart contract without knowing the private key of deployer

Tags: contract-development, blockchain

I am writing an NFT smart contract for a client. Is there a way that I can deploy this contract using the private keys of his wallet so that he is set as owner while at the same not not being able to see it?

How do blockchain developers deploy contracts for their clients without the client needing to trust the developer?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to deploy a contract from someone else's address without knowing the private key. However, there are some workarounds. You can create a javascript function (using web3/ethers) that will deploy the contract. Your client can call the function and approve it using their wallet.

A much better way would be to deploy it yourself and then transfet the ownership to your client. This will be trivial to execute if you are using `Owanable.sol` from Openeppelin. However, you'll end up paying the gas fee for the contract creation.

Comment: I am using Ownable.sol, i have some functions that are onlyOwner. What I thought about was since he does trust me I could set it up so that we have 2 accounts. 1 for deploying the contract (of which i know the private keys) and the other I send all payments to, and I dont know his private keys.

Comment: You could do that too. Although transferring ownership would be an easier approach.

Comment: OK gonna read more into that thanks for the heads up. Just checking it’s a function in ownable right

Comment: Yeah, you can check out the Ownable.sol contract or OpenZeppelin Docs